# Need some advices | Java - MVC Pattern - Client/Server Achitecture & protocol implementation

Tags: java, model-view-controller, client, protocols

***Part 1 : MVC pattern client/server architecture***

I have to program a client/server based application. So I want to implement the MVC pattern on the client-side. But my question is, which part of the MVC design opens sockets and send data to the server ? Is it the View ? The Model ? or the Controler ?

I imagined this :

User --> View --> Controler --> Model ====NETWORK ==== --> SERVER
In my case, the Model sends data to the server. What do you think about that ? Any suggestions ?

***Part 2 : Protocol implementation***

My second question is, how do you implement a protocol ? Just correct me if I'm wrong, but let's imagine I have a "DOWNLOAD FILE" button on the VIEW, and I want that this DOWNLOAD button downloads a file hosted on the server. Do you send a String (ex : "DOWNLOAD FILE") to the server ? So that when the server sees this String, it redirects you the correct method ? Do you send an Object which contains (Command Name, File to Download, etc...) ??
Any best practices ?

Thanks for reading me !

Comment: so you mean, all of these View --> Controler --> Model will be on client side?

Comment: Please clarify: Are you implementing *everything* yourself, from Socket connection up, or are you planning on using some framework or another (JavaEE on the server side, JSF for Views etc)? Because depending on your used framework there will be huge differences in the answers.

Comment: Usually it would be the Controller which handles network operations and uses the Model to store/retrieve data.

Comment: As for implementing a protocol, you're free to do as you please. Although maybe you should Google around for some more information, as you seem to be quite lost and this question is too broad for here.

Comment: Abu : Yes, the complete MVC would be on client side, but again is the correct thing to do ? Thanks.

Comment: Simon Hellinger : I wanted to implement everything myself (thread pool, MVC, sockets, protocol). But if I can do it with a Framework, why not ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are implementing a web application, I suggest that you read up on the existing architecture that some Frameworks already implement.  Try Spring MVC or Stripes Framework or Oracle ADF for size.

Comment: I would assume that he is not implementing a web application, since he talks about his own protocols.

Comment: Maybe the OP can give us more information then.  Is he thinking of writing his own client in Java as well?

Comment: The OP ? And yes, I plan to write everything in Java.

Comment: user2310289 : It is not a web application. There is a Java Client, and a Java Server. Sorry, maybe I forgot to mention it :)